# I want to make a program in discord.py that mention's someone, when someone joins

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I want to make a program in `discord.py` which which **mention's a member in a specific channel when he/she joins**
I made some code but don't what write ahead

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
```

Please help me!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    channel = discord.utils.get(member.guild.text_channels, name='channel name')
    await channel.send(f'{member.mention} Thanks for joining')
```